# Set fixed size and drawable style for each ImageView

Tags: java, android, imageview, android-linearlayout

My current try:

```
            ImageView imageview = new ImageView(this);
            imageview.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.nice_style));
            URL url = new URL("url_of_the_photo");
            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
            imageview.setImageBitmap(bmp);
            linear_layout.addView(imageview);
```

Doesn't use `nice_style` and I am not sure how I could apply fixed size for each imageview. I tried adding `LinearLayout.LayoutParams`, but I can set only `width` or `height`, not both.

Comment: use this imageview.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(width, height));

Answer (score 1):

use this for giving giving height and width to imageview.

```
imageview.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(width, height));
```

Comment: It seems to work, thanks. What about that `drawable`?

Comment: i m not getting there is only one imageview

Comment: it just doesn't apply that drawable

Comment: if your image is in drawable folder thn use only thismageview.setImageDrawable(R.drawable.nice_style);

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43768/discussion-between-mayuri-and-good-evening)